# Filtering $_REQUEST array based on another array?

Tags: php, arrays, request

Array `$ALLOWED_CALLS` contains a function name and required parameters. I'd like to filter `$_REQUEST` array obtaining a `$params` array with only required paramets in it. How to?

```
$call = 'translate';

$ALLOWED_CALLS = array(
    'getLanguages' => array(),
    'detect' => array('text'),
    'translateFrom' => array('text', 'from', 'to'),
    'translate' => array('text', 'to'),
);

$params = array(); // Should contain $_REQUEST['text'] and $_REQUEST['to']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) like so:

```
$params = array_intersect_key($_REQUEST, array_flip($ALLOWED_CALLS[$call]));
```

Thus, the whole thing:

```
$call = 'translate';

$ALLOWED_CALLS = array(
    'getLanguages' => array(),
    'detect' => array('text'),
    'translateFrom' => array('text', 'from', 'to'),
    'translate' => array('text', 'to'),
);

$params = array_intersect_key($_REQUEST, array_flip($ALLOWED_CALLS[$call]));
```

Comment: +1 Possibly also check if $call exists as a key in $ALLOWED_CALLS for completeness.

Comment: @liquorvicar Sure, can't argue with that. Another thing that might be desired is checking that `text` and `to` (in this case) both exist where expected. As is, this code will include them in `$params` _if_ they exist in `$_REQUEST`, but there's currently nothing ensuring that they do exist in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [array_intersect()](http://uk.php.net/array_intersect)

Comment: Better yet, array_intersect_key

Comment: Yes, that would work better. I was hoping just to point the OP in the right general direction so he could work it out for himself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$contains_required = true;
foreach( $ALLOWED_CALLS[$call] as $key => $value )
{
    if(!in_array($value, $_REQUEST))
    {
        $contains_required = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParams ($call, $allowedCalls) {
  // Return FALSE if the call was invalid
  if (!isset($allowedCalls[$call])) return FALSE;
  // Get allowed params from $_REQUEST into result array
  $result = array();
  foreach ($allowedCalls[$call] as $param) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$param])) {
      $result[$param] = $_REQUEST[$param];
    }
  }
  // Return the result
  return $result;
}
```

Returns the $params array, or `FALSE` on failure.